# How to change all text with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to build a chrome app that finds all the strings that look like a telephone and replaces them with a link. I want to only happen for text elements so it doesn't break javascript functions from the websites that the app runs on.

This is what I have so far:

```
var regex = /((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}(?!([^<]*>)|(((?!<a).)*<\/a>))/g;
var text = $("body:first").html();
text = text.replace(regex, "<a href=\"https://www.mylink.com/number=$&\">$&</a>");
$("body:first").html(text);
```

but it breaks if there are javascript

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code just retrieves the markup representation of the current state of the DOM, and overwrites that, losing all event bindings and a lot of other significant data.

What you'll need to do is to iterate through all the text nodes. You can't reach text nodes by the sizzle selector alone, so you'll need to rely on jQuery's [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) function.

You could do something like this to get all the text nodes:

```
var allTextNodes = $('*').contents().filter(function() { 
   return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
});
```